# How to change function input parameter name by Rcpp? Want R function input name to contain "dot"

Tags: c++, r, c, rcpp, r-package

I am writing an R package by Rcpp.
And I have a function in .cpp called

```
NumericVector rxkcd(double stdc,int n, bool swap_end_points)
```

I successfully build the package and has an R function

```
rxkcd(stdc = ? ,n= ? ,swap_end_points= ?)
```

But I want a function like this

```
rxkcd(stdc = 1 ,n= ? ,swap.end.points= FALSE)
```

But C won't allow the use of "dot" for the parameter's name.

What should I do to change the function input parameter name?

Besides, I also want to set `swap.end.points= FALSE` by default.

I am a beginner at writing an R package.

Thank you!

Comment: it's possible that you just can't do this (dots have semantic meaning in C++)

Comment: Ben is correct. You can't.  The _interface_ has to satisfy _both_ R and C++.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, post as answer?  Seems definitive.

Comment: I am fairly certain it is a duplicate as it is too obvious a question but I don't have time to dig right now.

Comment: C or C++ make up your mind.  Not that it makes a difference to the answer.